# Using Sublime Text 2 key bindings in PyCharm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext, pycharm, keymapping

I would like to use the Sublime Text 2 key bindings in Pycharm. I know how to edit it one by one. Is there a way to override the entire keymap in one shot?

Something like

- export the key bindings from sublime text 2
- convert it into Pycharm's format
- import it into Pycharm

Pycharm has some pre-configured keymaps. If there's a text / XML / JSON file where these maps are stored, I can try to convert it myself.

[image]

Comment: I personally prefer the IntelliJ key bindings, but this is a good question.

Comment: It may be a good question, but not for StackOverflow. It is off-topic.

Comment: Please note [the answer by myusuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999843/using-sublime-text-2-key-bindings-in-pycharm/56227753#56227753). I think it is now the right answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PyCharm now has Sublime Text keymap inbuilt as an alternative to Default Keymap.

Go to `Setting -> Keymap` and select `Sublime Text` from `Keymap` dropdown.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

After poking around, I feel there's no easy way to do this.

If you change the default bindings, PyCharm creates a file in [user space](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) that shows the format of keymap. Theoretically, one could override all the fields in this file. But the problem is, there's no standard way of describing the `action` performed by a shortcut. Someone will have to do it manually, for each macro, to establish a correspondence between the actions performed by PyCharm & Sublime Text.

Comment: If you pulled this off, it would be awesome if you could share the configs file.

Answer (score 3):

There is an IntelliJ request for this in their Youtrack tracker: [IDEA-111333 Provide Sublime Text keymap](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111333).

From that thread, I found a [repository for another remapping project](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/PHPStorm-SpacePeacock). The keybinding file that imitates most of Sublime text can be found at in [the directory `PHPStorm-SpacePeacock/win_linux-keymaps-only/keymaps/Default for GNOME copy.xml`](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/PHPStorm-SpacePeacock/blob/master/win_linux-keymaps-only/keymaps/Default%20for%20GNOME%20copy.xml). From the README:

> The key mapping has been updated to better fit Sublime Text
>   conventions. Because I didn't think that `ctrl + shift + alt + t` is a
>   reasonable key combination for something as frequently used as
>   **Refactor This**.
>
> Additionally, "search everywhere" HAD to be changed because
>   double-tapping left-shift is a two stroke trigger. This is a problem
>   because as you're working the IDE will be busy with analyzing,
>   indexing, and all of the things that IDEs do. If it's busy when you
>   try to hit the first left-shift, then the second left-shift won't pop
>   up the window. As far as user interfaces go, you should never have any
>   lack of confidence that an action will trigger the appropriate
>   response. Once you have that, you have to visually check each
>   operation which is slow and creates cognitive overhead. Consequently,
>   this was changed to `ctrl + p` (also to match Sublime Text) which
>   completely removes this problem.
>
> `ctrl + p` search everywhere
>
> `ctrl + r` search methods in current file
>
> `ctrl + alt + p` change projects
>
> `ctrl + shift + enter` complete current statement
>
> `ctrl + alt + enter` refactor this
>
> `alt + enter` show intended actions (intentions are one of my favorite
>   part JetBrains software)
>
> `ctrl + n` new thing dialog
>
> `ctrl + shift + f` format code
>
> `ctrl + d` select word at cursor, or if a word is selected the select
>   the next occurrence of the word (multiple-cursors)
>
> `ctrl + t` run tests
>
> `ctrl + alt + h` show local history
>
> `ctrl + alt + r` git conflict merge tool

Comment: I tried both the @maggie osx one and the one here. This ones works better on linux.
Just copy the keymap file called "Default copy for GNOME" to /home/<username>/.PyCharm50/config/keymaps
Restart pycharm and select it in pycharm.

Comment: @tal do you mean from the GitHub link?

Comment: I have since figured out that he did mean from the GitHub link. Notice that if you have a Setting Repository, the link to copy your keymaps will be different.

Answer (score 0):

(Less popular) keymaps that can be used with JetBrains Rider but not included in the installation package. 
https://github.com/JetBrains/rider-non-bundled-keymaps

**Intalling keymaps**

In releases, get the sublime-text-keymap.jar file for the desired keymap.

In your IDE, choose File | Import Settings... from the menu and select the sublime-text-keymap.jar file.

Comment: The question is really off-topic for StackOVerflow, and by consequence this answer is too.